# How to navigate when using `Next-intl` and `next/link`

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, next.js14, next-intl

I implemented a `next-intl` for multi-language support. So my paths look like `www.next.com/de` or `www.next.com/en`

I'm using `NextJS 14`.

```
<NextLink href="/support-us">{t("About us")}</NextLink>
```

And when I want to navigate to for example `/support-us` it must navigate me to `/en/support-us` instead I get to `/support-us` so it throws an error.

> NotFoundError: Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': The node to
> be removed is not a child of this node.

Here is my code.
`middleware.ts`

```
import createMiddleware from "next-intl/middleware";
import { locales } from "./i18n";

export default createMiddleware({
  // A list of all locales that are supported
  locales,

  // Used when no locale matches
  defaultLocale: "en",
});

export const config = {
  // Match only internationalized pathnames
  matcher: ["/", "/(en|it|de|nl|fr|sv|es|nb|pt|pl)/:path*"],
};
```

`i18next`

```
import { notFound } from "next/navigation";
import { getRequestConfig } from "next-intl/server";

interface Language {
  symbol: string;
  name: string;
}

export const supportedLanguages: Language[] = [
  { symbol: "EN", name: "English" },
  { symbol: "DE", name: "Deutsch" },

];

const languageSymbolsLowercase: string[] = supportedLanguages.map((lang) =>
  lang.symbol.toLowerCase()
);

const initialLocales: string[] = [];

const combinedLocales: string[] = [
  ...initialLocales,
  ...languageSymbolsLowercase,
];

export const locales: string[] = combinedLocales;

export default getRequestConfig(async ({ locale }) => {
  if (!locales.includes(locale)) notFound();

  return {
    messages: (await import(`../messages/${locale}.json`)).default,
  };
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end I had to add a `navigation file` as mentioned in the [next-intl documentation](https://next-intl-docs.vercel.app/docs/routing/navigation) in there it exports a `Link` component which solves the problem and navigates to `/[locale]/support-us`
for example `/en/support-us` here is my `navigation` file

```
import {
  createLocalizedPathnamesNavigation,
  Pathnames,
} from "next-intl/navigation";
import { locales } from "./i18n";

export const localePrefix = "always"; // Default

export const pathnames = {
  "/support-us": "/support-us",
} satisfies Pathnames<typeof locales>;

export const { Link, redirect, usePathname, useRouter, getPathname } =
  createLocalizedPathnamesNavigation({ locales, localePrefix, pathnames });
```

And use the `Link` exported in the navigation file

```
import { Link as NavLink } from "@navigation"
<NavLink href="/support-us">{t("support us")}</NavLink>
```

Answer (score 1):

To explicitly include the locale in your paths, you can use the `useRouter` hook from `next/navigation` (in `nextjs 14`) to access the current locale, and then prepend it to your paths.

Here's how you could adjust your `<NextLink>` usage to incorporate the current locale:

```
"use client"
import { useRouter } from 'next/navigation';

const SupportUs = () => {
  const router = useRouter();
  const { locale } = router;

  return (
    <NextLink href={`/${locale}/support-us`}>{t("About us")}</NextLink>
  );
};
```

**UPDATE:** I tried to simulate your use case on my end, and I think you can achieve your desired result on the server side by adjusting your `middleware.ts` file. You won't need to modify your component/page file though.

So, below is the updated `middleware.ts` that I tried to revise:

```
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';
import type { NextRequest } from 'next/server';
import createMiddleware from 'next-intl/middleware';
import { locales } from './i18n';

// Your existing createMiddleware setup
const intlMiddleware = createMiddleware({
  locales,
  defaultLocale: 'en',
});

export default function middleware(req: NextRequest) {
  // Attempt to retrieve the locale from the previous URL
  const referer = req.headers.get('referer');
  let refererLocale = '';

  if (referer) {
    // Extract the locale from the URL path in the Referer header
    const pathLocaleMatch = referer.match(/\/\/[^/]+\/([^/]+)/);
    if (pathLocaleMatch && locales.includes(pathLocaleMatch[1])) {
      refererLocale = pathLocaleMatch[1];
    }
  }

  // Fallback to the default locale if no valid locale was found in the Referer
  const effectiveLocale = refererLocale || 'en';

  // Check if the current request's URL already includes a locale
  const hasLocale = locales.some(locale => req.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith(`/${locale}`));
  if (!hasLocale) {
    // If not, redirect to the same URL but with the effective locale prefixed
    const url = req.nextUrl.clone();
    url.pathname = `/${effectiveLocale}${url.pathname}`;
    return NextResponse.redirect(url);
  }

  // Proceed with the next-intl middleware if the locale is already present
  return intlMiddleware(req);
}

export const config = {
  // Match only internationalized pathnames
  matcher: ['/', '/(en|it|de|nl|fr|sv|es|nb|pt|pl)/:path*'],
};
```

I hope this could resolve your issue in a better approach.

Comment: I think with that I should use `"use client"` too right?

Comment: Yes, absolutely. Also, I've made slight updates on my answer due to `next.js 14` updates.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. How can I use it on the serverside?

Comment: So I'm using `usetranslations` and when I add `"use client"` it says I cannot use `usetranslations` in a client side component

Comment: You may have to use `getServerSideProps` or `getStaticProps` to pass transaltions to client components as props. That way, the translations can be fetched from server-side and made available to your client component.

Comment: Can you guid me to `getStaticProps` for your approach? that would be great!

Comment: @Yaya - I tried to simulate your case on my end, and updated my answer. I think we can achieve the goal on the server side with `middleware` without changing your local component/page files. Please check if that works.

Comment: But I still get the same result how can that be? could you share a sandbox of your code?

Comment: I think I got it. The problem is with my matcher in the `config`.  because when I remove `config` it works absolutely fine the problem is, now fonts won't be loaded and alongside fonts all the `js` won't work either